# Inserting a list into a 2D array with a given index

Tags: python, arrays

I could not quite find the exact answer I was looking for in the community.

I am trying to insert a list into a 2D array, with a specific index. For example, here is my 2D array:

```
array = [
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
[6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
]
```

And here is my new list:

`newList = ["f", "g", "h", "i", "j"]`

How would I insert the `newList` to `array` such that:

```
array = [
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
["f", "g", "h", "i", "j"]
["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
[6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
]
```

Thanks! Please let me know if anything sounds unclear.

Comment: You mean `array.insert(1, newList)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your array is just a list, you can use insert

```
array = [
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"],
[6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
]

newList = ["f", "g", "h", "i", "j"]

array.insert(2, newList)
```

Returns

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'],
['f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j'],
[6, 7, 8, 9, 10]]
```

Comment: oh what,,, so simple. Thank you!